# Not using THAT in non-defining relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

While I was teaching ***non-defining relative*** clauses in an intermediate book, one of my students asked why ***that*** cannot be use?! I don't remember reading any tips about it. Is there a logical explanation?

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that "that" is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator.

Comment: But the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English has listed THAT along with WHO and WHICH as a relative pronoun!

Comment: The golden rule is never use dictionaries for grammar! Grammarians recognise that "that" cannot be a relative pronoun for several reasons. In fact it is a meaningless marker of subordination, the same "that" that introduces declarative content clauses. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/that)